# Scrapy and Wikipedia, getting empty strings

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm a Python beginner and this is my first question here. I'm trying to scrape the titles and urls from this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2013_films)  and store them in .json. Preliminary xpath testing in scrapy shell with

```
sel.xpath('//tr[@style="vertical-align: top;"]//a')
```

in terminal shows urls and titles within  tags, but complete script returns .json file with empty strings like this:

```
[{"url": [], "title": []},
{"url": [], "title": []},
{"url": [], "title": []},
{"url": [], "title": []}],
```

Here is the whole script:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from wikipedia.items import WikipediaItem


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2013_films"
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//tr[@style="vertical-align: top;"]//li')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = WikipediaItem()
            item["url"] = sel.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            item["title"] = sel.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)  
        return(items)
```

If you can give me a hint where am I doing wrong, would be just great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed `parse()` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    titles = sel.xpath('//tr[@style="vertical-align: top;"]//li')
    for title in titles:
        item = WikipediaItem()
        link = title.xpath("a")
        if link:
            item["url"] = link.xpath("@href").extract()[0]
            item["title"] = link.xpath("text()").extract()[0]
        yield item
```

prints:

```
{'title': u'+1 (film)', 'url': u'/wiki/%2B1_(film)'}
{'title': u'10,000 Hours', 'url': u'/wiki/10,000_Hours'}
...
```

Note that the only thing you did wrong is that you should have searched using xpath inside a `title` instead of using `sel`.

Also note that instead of gathering extracted items into a list and then returning them, you can `yield` items right from the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going mad to be honest :)))